# Using the solution to an equation in another function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, function-construction, special-functions

I am trying to use the solution to 
$R^2 \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\text{Erf}[r/4]\right)=r^2$ for $r$ in the function

Potential$(R)=\frac{1}{R^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\text{Erf}\left(r/4\right)\right)$

and plot this between $R=0$ and $R=5$. Essentially for each value of $R$, I want to solve the first equation for $r$ and then insert that $r$ into the second equation and plot. I use the code

```
T[R_] = First[r /. Solve[R^2 (1 - 1/r Erf[r/4]) == r^2, r, Reals]]
Potential[R_] = 1/R^2 (1 - 1/T[R] Erf[T[R]/4])
Plot[Potential[R], {R, 0, 5}]
```

However, T[R_] outputs $r$, which is not what I want, and then Potential[R_] outputs $(1 - (2 Erf[r/4])/r)/R^2$. Any ideas? I have tried using NSolve instead of Solve but this does not help.

Comment: it returns `r` simply because `Solve` cant solve that. Do you imagine that equation should have an analytic solution?

Comment: I think it should, using NSolve then for example 
First[r /. NSolve[5^2 (1 - 1/r Erf[r/4]) == r^2, r, Reals]]

gives 

-4.47771

Comment: of course, `NSolve` can numerically handle many things, where `Solve` can not obtain an analytic soluton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the plot can be obtained numerically.

```
T[R_?NumericQ] := First[r /. NSolve[R^2 (1 - 1/r Erf[r/4]) == r^2, r, Reals]] 
Potential[R_?NumericQ] := 1/R^2 (1 - 1/T[R] Erf[T[R]/4]) 
Plot[Potential[R], {R, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Note that `Potential` is singular at `R == 0`, so it might be more informative to plot.

```
Plot[R^2 Potential[R], {R, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

FYI you can do that plot parametrcially and avoid numerically solving for `r` :

```
RR[r_] = R /. Solve[R^2 (1 - 1/r Erf[r/4]) == r^2, R] // First
pot[r_] = 1/RR[r]^2 (1 - 1/r Erf[r/4])
ParametricPlot[{RR[r], RR[r]^2 pot[r]}, {r, -5, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or, another way could be find the solution for several numbers (x,y) and then interpolate as Interpolate will create a function for you.

```
interpF = Interpolation[datalist_as_x_y_pairs];
```

then

```
interpF[any_x] will get you the y value you are looking for
```